# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings use another config file

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I have about 10 methods in my class. In every method I use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to get value form App.config file

like

```
 _applicationPort = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationPort"]
```

My problem is that I want to make this code get AppSettings from another app.config file like AnotherPoject.exe.config.

Answer (score 18):

You can also set the `app.config` to read another file. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings  file="my\custom\file\path\external.config"/>
</configuration>
```

and the `external.config` will have the appSettings section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue" />
</appSettings>
```

refer to [this msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for additional info.

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this

```
var fileConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("<filePath>");
int port = int.Parse(fileConfig.AppSettings["PortNumber"].ToString());
```

Comment: `fileConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PortNumber"].ToString()` is what i needed

Comment: Settings is a KeyValueConfigurationCollection, so the .Value property needs to be accessed.  Also, no need for .ToString() as Value is already a string.
`fileConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PortNumber"]?.Value`

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`.  This will allow you to open another configuration file easily.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) article about OpenExeConfiguration.