# Class is inherited from abstract class which is in another project. How to use a value from app.config from original project?

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I have abstract class:

```
namespace Project1 
{
   public abstract class AbstractManager
   {
       public readonly string SomeSetting =
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeSetting"];
   }
}
```

I have a class which is inherited from this abstract class and located in another project:

```
namespace Project2 
{
   public class SpecificManager : AbstractManager
   {        
   }
}
```

The problem is when I create **SpecificManager** it uses value from app.config of **Project2** for **SomeSetting**, but I want it to uses value from app.config of **Project1**. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: not by default ... you need to point the config file in Project1 ... ConfigurationManager will always take config from executable config (I assumed the you have Project1.dll and Project2.exe with their configs)

Comment: @Selvin you mean like here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425407/configurationmanager-appsettings-use-another-config-file)? I really don't like this solution, maybe I can do it somehow differently?

Comment: @Gelo Can you use a Settings file? This is "bound" to the project it's placed in. And as a positive side effect, you get strong types by selecting the type you want to have for that setting (so no casting/parsing required).